# Animate translate3d and scale with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

So I have a css command that edits the 3d translation of an object and its scale simultaneously to different values.

```
_this.css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d('+X+'px, '+Y+'px, 0) scale('+scaleFactor+', '+scaleFactor+')');
```

This works great but it happens instantly, I want to animate it using jquery similarly to how you can animate width and height. So the solution I keep seeing on SO is a variation of this.

```
$('#foo').animate({  borderSpacing: -90 }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
      $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');  
    },
    duration:'slow'
},'linear');
```

Where borderSpacing is some value set to 0, the end goal would be -90 and it would step and slowly rotate. however this only works for one variable is it possible for me to do this when I have 3 totally different variables? and if so how? In the aforementioned solution the stepping creates a now variable that is some incremental step towards the final goal but when I have 3 independent variables I am not sure how this could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You best route would be to just apply a css rule to your element

```
#foo{
   transition: all 700ms linear;
}
```

and use the first part of your script only (*where you apply the new transform values*)

---

If you have to go the `.animate` way then the object can hold more than one properties and the `step` function will be called for each one

```
$('#foo').animate({  borderSpacing: -90, otherProp: 80 }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
      switch(fx.prop){
          case 'borderSpacing': 
               $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
               break;
          case 'otherProp':
               $(this).css('something else', now);
               break;
      }
    },
    duration:'slow'
},'linear');
```